# Long Numeric Strings

Tags: excel, cell, progress-4gl, openedge

When generating data/item's code that resembles a scientific number (e.g 124E12) from Progress to Excel, Excel will display it on cell as 1.24E+10. I tried to set excel's cell as text and general before generating but it will still treat it as Scientific. Also tried to use Number and it displayed 124000000000000.

Comment: Perhaps you have problems with the decimal and thousand separators? How does Progress export "one million" 1.000.000,00 or 1,000,000.00 or 1000000.00 or or 1000000,00 something else? And: how do you want it to export?

Comment: i want it to export is as it is.. if its 124E10 then it should display as 124E10.. Tried to add a character in the code and it works by the way but it will also display the same character in the excel cell ( below the ~ somewhere in upper part of keyboard. had to comment this way since it SO will display it as code )

Comment: Is it stored like a string "124E10" in the database/variable?

Comment: yes.. it does.... no quotes btw

Comment: Now I see, 124E12 and 1,24E10 is actually the same so I guess it's up to how you change the display format in excel.

Comment: Yeah i tried to change it to 3 different format, text, general and number and it did not help.. so i had to add a character (below ~) so that it will display as string in excel but it will also display the character in excel..

Comment: Please be precise in mathematics. 124E12 = 1.24E+14 = 124000000000000. So the 1.24E+10 cannot be the result with your example. If Excel shall display the number 124000000000000 as 124E12, then try with the format `000E-00`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]You need to change the display format in Excel.

I'm on a Swedish version of Excel so names below might not be translated the right way.

1) Select the cell/row and right-click. Choose Format Cell in the menu.

2) Choose "Custom format" or similar (in the end of the list).

3) Type `##0,000E+00` and press "OK".